# Srping Security + Zuul + Nginx Authentication error handling

Tags: spring-boot, nginx, spring-security, netflix-zuul

I have [Zuul](https://github.com/Netflix/zuul) and Backend Srping Boot applications and it works just fine without nginx.
So normally it works like that:

1. User is at `http://localhost:8080/auth/login`
2. User types wrong login and password and sends it
3. User is redirected to `http://localhost:8080/auth/login?error` and is able to see error message.

Zuul is running on port 8080 and `/auth/` is auth application running on another port but I can reach it through Zuul application without knowing exact location of auth application.

But with Nginx user is redirected back to `http://localhost:8080/auth/login` where `?error` is missing and user can't see the error message.

I tried to configure Nginx to use https and to forward requests to my Zuul app that forwads requests to Spring application itself (where Spring Security is).

```
   server {

        # Add index.php to the list if you are using PHP
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html login.html login.htm;
    server_name servername.com; # managed by Certbot

                

        location /auth/ {
                access_log off;
                proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
                proxy_pass http://zuul_ip:8080/auth/;
        }

        gzip on;
        gzip_disable "msie6";
        gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript;



   listen [::]:443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
   listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/servename.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/servername.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
   include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
   ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot


}
server {
    if ($host = servername.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

     listen 80 ;
     listen [::]:80 ;
     server_name servername.com;
     return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

So I need user is redirected back correctly with query param is not deleted from url. How can I achieve this?